Has the Canadian government released any evidence regarding the Indian interior minister's involvement in the assassination?

Canada accuses India’s Amit Shah over campaign targeting Sikh separatists


Deputy Foreign Affairs Minister David Morrison confirmed to the members of the national security committee late on Tuesday that the government considers Shah – considered India’s second-highest leader and a close ally of Prime Minister Narendra Modi – the architect of the campaign against Sikh separatists in Canada, which has included the assassination of an activist.

Has the Canadian government released any evidence regarding the Indian interior minister's, Amit Shah's, involvement in the assassination of Hardeep Singh Nijjar?
If not, why did the Canadian minister publicly accuse the Indian minister for interior?

I know that hardly counts as an answer, but I don't know if we should expect much to be shared publicly due the exposure it gives to the sources.  Look for the presence/absence of support from some of its partner governments which will have received secret briefings.  In the past year, they did ask India to collaborate in the investigations rather than asking Trudeau to pipe down.

Re. "VTC cuz discredit"  Nah, let's leave it open.  As a Canadian, high level disputes with India are going to affect us somewhat so we might as well know more.  I don't know what will come of this question, but I don't see any great benefit in shutting it down.

The only part of the question with issues is "If not, why did the Canadian minister publicly accuse the Indian minister for interior?" as the way this is framed is asking us to peer into the mind of the Canadian minister. This secondary question should be removed or edited.


why did the Canadian minister publicly accuse the Indian minister for interior?

This part is somewhat easier to answer. It's a clarification of earlier RCMP statements that the campaign was ordered at the "highest levels" in India.

"We do have strong evidence — not intelligence, but evidence — that this goes all the way up to the highest level," Commissioner Mike Duheme told CBC Power & Politics host David Cochrane on Friday.
"Some of the evidence I am referring to will eventually come out through the judicial process."
[...] Duheme said the Mounties first tried to share evidence linking crimes in Canada to the upper levels of Indian Prime Minister Narendra Modi's government with the Indian police, but were unsuccessful.
[...] Duheme said he couldn't comment on the evidence.

So, the evidence is not public for now but the RCMP and the government appear confident enough to state that it exist and will be revealed during the judicial process.
If I'm to add the Indian viewpoint here, they say none of this is true and it's all about "vote bank politics" in Canada.
By the by, this is somewhat reminiscent of the Turkish strategy in the Khashoggi murder, in which they first said they had evidence, let the Saudis deny it, then revealed it piece by piece. Whether Canada has enough evidence to pull off something similar, I guess we'll see.  (BTW, after extracting some political capital over that but also getting the butt of [unofficial] Saudi economic sanctions, Turkey ultimately agreed to transfer the judicial process to Riyadh.)
